# Procedural texture creating rough edges

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor, displacement, bump

I'm new to blender, and I decided to model a cookie to develop some basic skills. I'm practically finished, but I'm running across a problem. The bottom part of the cookie looks really spiky and low poly, picture here:

[image]

I am not sure how to fix it, any suggestions?

Node setup for the cookie here:

[image]

Comment: What are your _Subdivision Surface_ modifier settings, if any?

Comment: Maybe try connecting the third noise (the one to the Subtracts, Max-s and Min-s) with the vector you are using, i.e. Object Coordinates?

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 I'm sorry, nodes confuse me, can you tell me specifically which output to connect to which input?

Comment: @RobinBetts I applied my subdivision surface long ago, although I believe I only changed "levels" to 3.

Comment: @DollarStoreRichard Try taking the "Object" output from the Texture Coordinate node and plug it into the Vector input of the noise, that doesnt have one. You can also try to add another subsurf, without applying it, just to see if it will fix it.

Comment: @TheMadTomato1209 Subdivision surface did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @DollarStoreRichard Glad to hear that!